# How to Disable All Certificate Checks in Firefox, including HSTS?

Tags: firefox, security

I'm a firm believer that security is overrated, so I want to disable `HTTPS` to avoid getting all these messages in Firefox:

> Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

How does one do that? There was `security.mixed_content.use_hstsc` but it has been removed. Is there a single option in Firefox to disable the certificate checks?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have concerns, I won't go into asking *why* you believe security to be overrated. The following answer is just speculation about how you *could* do such things if you really needed to.

If you are familiar with proxies, you can use a tool called [SSLStrip](https://avicoder.me/2016/02/22/SSLstrip-for-newbies/) which will essentially remove HTTPS from everything coming in. However, that won't work for pinned websites, where the domain is already in a local list of sites for which the browser will demand HTTPS, or refuse to connect. Popular websites and online banking sites like PayPal are in this list. In those cases, you could use your proxy or gateway to sign everything using its own custom root certificate, and you [install that certificate in your Firefox browser](https://wiki.wmtransfer.com/projects/webmoney/wiki/Installing_root_certificate_in_Mozilla_Firefox).

Comment: The problem with security is that it implies you have something to hide, which is itself a problem - somebody forces you to hide your communication. Now instead of treating the real problem, i.e. not being able to say transmit child porn or calls to overthrow authoritarian government in open, without being arrested, you treat the symptom of the problem instead. Ideally there should be no reason for security at all.